# PHP: make a 'fake'/custom statement in while

Tags: php, pdo

I have this while loop.

`while($show = $queryActivities->fetch()){ echo $show["name"]."<br>"; }`

This takes data from the query and outputs the names..

Now is it possible to make a custom/fake data? I would like to make one if theres no data/statement in the $queryActivities then it should make a custom one called "name" with value "Nothing here.."

Is this possible? Can you do that?

I know I can do `if($queryActivities->rowCount == 0){ echo "Nothing here" ; }`

But I more thought of creating a custom data, so it runs the while loop, with the custom data, that only gets made if theres nothing in $queryActivities.

Something like..:

```
if($queryActivities->rowCount == 0){
 # ..MAKE CUSTOM DATA..
 # ..SOMETHING LIKE THIS MAYBE:  .. 
 # $queryActivities = MAKE ARRAY WITH name => 'Nothing here'.. (just a thought)
}
while ($show = $queryActivities->fetch()){
echo $show["name"]."<br>";
}
```

Something like this, just what I imagine, although I dont know really how.

Thank you

Comment: So if $queryActivities has nothing to fetch (rows are 0) then make a fake/custom one, with name = 'nothing here' so it can run the loop atleast once and say nothing is there..

Comment: you can just do this `if($queryActivities->rowCount == 0) { echo ...; return; }`, does not seems necessary to faking a loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrieve your data to an array, and then print it out. In between these two steps, you can modify it as desired.

This is more orderly, anyhow. I don't like retrieving from the DB and displaying in one step

You could either have an if/else that checks if the array is empty and prints a default message, or creates a default entry with a 'name' property that then is displayed with the same output loop as normal data. I'd prefer the first, but we'll do the second style since that's what you asked about.

Here's one simple solution.

```
$activities=array();
while($show = $queryActivities->fetch()){ $activities[]=$show; }

if(empty($activities)){ $activities=array(array('name'=>'None Found')); }

foreach($activities as $activity){
   echo $activity['name']."<br>";
   }
```

I think just using an if/else is a better solution. Depending on your output style, though, this might involve more code repetition.

```
$activities=array();
while($show = $queryActivities->fetch()){ $activities[]=$show; }

if(empty($activities)){ 
   echo "None found <br>";
   }

else{
   foreach($activities as $activity){
     echo $activity['name']."<br>";
     }
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply, truth is that I dont just have echo $show["name"]."<br>"; but with a css box, with name, picture, date, message etc from the $show. And i thought instead of duplicating(the code in while) the whole box etc (and insert in if(empty )) then maybe just make custom data, and fill those fields(name, picture) etc.. to code it smarter. guess you cant do this

Comment: @Karem Sure, I know what you mean. That's what I was thinking when I mentioned 'this might involve more code repetition.'. Go with the first style, then, and make a default data set.